# Printing a numerically incremented value

Tags: bash

Is this the proper way to print a numerically incremented value with printf in bash?

```
  for (( i=0 ; i < $nf ; i++ )); do
    printf ' %s %s\n' "$((i + 1)). ${fdir[$i]}"
  done
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible but I'd probably use a slightly different version:

```bash
for (( i=1 ; i <= nf ; i++ )) ; do
    printf ' %d. %s\n' "$i" "${fdir[i-1]}"
done
```

- Use `%d` for numbers, not `%s` (you can even use `%2d` to align on the dot);
- `printf` with two `%s`'s (or one `%d` and one `%s`) should get two arguments to print, not one;
- The dot should go to the format so that the arguments are the simplest possible;
- Array index already is a numeric expression, no need to introduce `$((...))`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are trying to print the whole array (i.e. that `$nf` is equal to `${#fdir[@]}`) another possibly more idiomatic option would be to use the `!` indirection operator to loop over the array's indices directly, rather than using a C-style loop:

```
for i in "${!fdir[@]}"; do printf '%d. %s\n' "$((i+1))" "${fdir[i]}"; done
```

As with the other answer, the `.`  is moved into the printf format string and the index and value are passed as separate arguments.

Comment: When using array indices, I do not need to use `$` such as in `fdir[$i]`?

Comment: @Red not so long as `fdir` is an indexed array - from `man bash`: *"The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number."*